# JavaScript function won't run after using header(), but does run if no use of header() (in php)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I apologize if my question title is at all confusing, this is my first post and despite reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic I feel like I may still have some flaws in my question-writing abilities.

**TL;DR:** JavaScript animation works if I do not use `header("location: ProjectUserProfile.php?UploadSuccessful")`, but doesn't if I do (and I need to). Any reasons or solutions?

Anyway,

**The context:**
I have a html form embedded in a php document which is used to upload an image, delete an image, etc.

The main code takes place on ProjectUserProfile.php (and works perfectly), and after the image has been uploaded, I use `header("location: ProjectUserProfile.php?UploadSuccessful")` to return to the page, and prompt a refresh.

**The problem:**
If I do not use `header("location: ProjectUserProfile.php?UploadSuccessful")`, the image will not change, etc, so it is a necessity for me to use it. However, recently I have implemented "slide in notifications" if you will which display success and error messages. These work correctly normally, but **fail** to appear if I return to the page using `header("location: ProjectUserProfile.php?UploadSuccessful")`.

```html
<?php
// all the uploading etc that works occurs here
header("location: ProjectUserProfile.php?UploadSuccessful");
echo "<script> openMessage('Information','The duplicate files were successfully uploaded!') </script>";
?>
```

After redirecting to ProjectUserProfile.php?UploadSuccessful, there is **failure** to acknowledge `openMessage`, and so nothing happens.

Whereas, had I not used `header("location: ProjectUserProfile.php?UploadSuccessful")`, the "notification" would slide in and work.

Does anyone have any solutions or suggestions?

*Relevant code for the javascript function 'openMessage()' below:*

```js
function openMessage(Purpose, DisplayText){
 var notificationDiv = document.getElementById("slideinNotification");
 if(notificationDiv){
  alert("exists");
 }
 else{
  alert("does not exist");
 }


 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
  if(Purpose == "Information"){
  document.getElementById("slideInNotification").style.backgroundColor = "#4CAF50";
  }
  else if(Purpose == "Warning"){
   document.getElementById("slideInNotification").style.backgroundColor = "#FF9800";
  }
  else if(Purpose == "Error"){
   document.getElementById("slideInNotification").style.backgroundColor = "#F44336";
  }
  document.getElementById("notificationMessage").innerHTML = DisplayText;
  moveElement();
 });
}
```

```html
<?php
if($filesWereDeleted == true){
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "project");
$result = $connection -> query("UPDATE UserProfileImage SET UploadStatus = 1 WHERE UserUniqueID = '$userProfileId'");
header("location: ProjectUserProfile.php?DeletionSuccessful");
echo "<script> openMessage('Information','The profile image was successfully deleted!') </script>";
}
?>



<div id = "slideInNotification" class = "slideNotification">
<p id = "notificationMessage" class = "notificationInfo"></p>
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" class = "closeButton" onclick = "closeMessage()">&times;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You're wanting the client side content to run before your server side redirect occurs. Unfortunately it does not work that way. Embed your JavaScript snippet into `ProjectUserProfile.php`. Don't forget that PHP is server side, JavaScript is client side...

Comment: Yeah I managed to find a somewhat rudimentary method of making it work, I used session variables such as $_SESSION["RedirectedReason"] to declare the reason, and then on the page reloading, it would run through a few if statements and execute the JS for the notification there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `UPDATE` query exposed to SQL Injection, if you get the id from the user, I hope note, read about prepared statement.

Second, about your problem, you echo the notify script in the same response you send the `Location` header , so before the the browser even load your JavaScript code it redirect the client to the new page when your notify javascript code not echoed...

If your problem is that user updates it's image and it's doesn't appear due it cached you can use `uniqid()` in the get query of image `src` or modify time, more effective

Comment: Ah yeah, I have yet to get to my SQL anti-injection proofing (as I want to make some basic things, such as this, to work first). In the end I managed to get it to work with some variables and taking advantage of the reload. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, once you use `header("location: ProjectUserProfile.php?DeletionSuccessful");` you're not supposed to write anything into the output, as the browser will ignore it. That aside, I'm not exactly sure about how a single line of `<script> openMessage('Information','The duplicate files were successfully uploaded!') </script>` could mean anything to the browser, since that wouldn't constitute an HTML document by itself, unless you're receiving it through AJAX or loading it into an `<iframe>`; but even then, I doubt mixing control instructions (a redirect) with view markup (the script tag) would be a good idea.

You're going to have to post the confirmation message in `ProjectUserProfile.php`, so move your script tag there. You can use that `?UploadSuccessful` bit as reference for you to know whether to include your script for the message in the document is necessary or not.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I managed to get it working again in the end. I would upvote your reply, but unfortunately I am too much of a noob to be able to (I need at least 15 points), but seriously thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Don't worry, I can just answer more questions in order to try and get some points. I'm glad to hear I was of help.